# tikz - draw a uml style note box

Tags: tikz-pgf

Can I draw a uml style note box with tikz?

Below picture is copied from UML:

[image]

I try it with tikz as below:

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes.multipart}

\definecolor{activityBackgroundColor}{RGB}{254,254,206}
\definecolor{activityBorderColor}{RGB}{168,0,54}
\definecolor{noteBackgroundColor}{RGB}{251,251,119}
\definecolor{noteBorderColor}{RGB}{168,0,54}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[every text node part/.style={align=center}]

\node (A) [draw=activityBorderColor,fill=activityBackgroundColor,rectangle,rounded corners,] {Hello \\ world};
\node[draw=noteBorderColor,fill=noteBackgroundColor,rectangle,right=2mm of A] {this is \\ a node};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

How can we get exactly the same style as uml note box?

Answer (score 4):

There is a `shapes.callout` library which comes close without much work. If you insist on the folded corner look, it's possible to create a new shape yourself (although quite a bit of work for that one detail, I suspect.)

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes.multipart,shapes.callouts}

\definecolor{activityBackgroundColor}{RGB}{254,254,206}
\definecolor{activityBorderColor}{RGB}{168,0,54}
\definecolor{noteBackgroundColor}{RGB}{251,251,119}
\definecolor{noteBorderColor}{RGB}{168,0,54}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[every text node part/.style={align=center}]

\node (A) [draw=activityBorderColor,fill=activityBackgroundColor,rectangle,rounded corners,] {Hello \\ world};
\node[draw=noteBorderColor,fill=noteBackgroundColor,rectangle callout,callout relative pointer={(-1,0)},right =of A] {this is \\ a node};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Answer (score 4):

If you would like to add the folded little corner to Alan Munn's answer:

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,%shapes.multipart,
    shapes.callouts}
\definecolor{activityBackgroundColor}{RGB}{254,254,206}
\definecolor{activityBorderColor}{RGB}{168,0,54}
\definecolor{noteBackgroundColor}{RGB}{251,251,119}
\definecolor{noteBorderColor}{RGB}{168,0,54}
\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[every text node part/.style={align=center}]
        \node (A) [draw=activityBorderColor,fill=activityBackgroundColor,rectangle,rounded corners] {Hello \\ world};
        \node[draw=noteBorderColor,fill=noteBackgroundColor,rectangle callout,callout relative pointer={(-1,0)},right =3em of A] (B) {this is \\ a node};
        \draw[white, fill=white] ([xshift=-4pt]B.north east) -- (B.north east) -- ([yshift=-4pt]B.north east);
        \draw[noteBorderColor, fill=noteBackgroundColor, line width=.4pt] ([shift={(-4pt,-.2pt)}]B.north east) -- ([shift={(-4pt,-4pt)}]B.north east)  [rounded corners=.01pt]-- ([shift={(-.2pt,-4pt)}]B.north east) -- cycle;
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice. It would be nice to make this a style such that the folded corner adapts to the direction of the callout pointer and also to the size of the callout rectangle.

Comment: @AlanMunn Thank you! I'll try to improve it :)